# Do not want to use Cast method

Tags: c#, .net, casting

I have an abstract class

```
public abstract ElementInfo : IElementMap, ISection
```

I have a method that accepts arguments of type List< IElementMap >

```
public static IDictionary<int,int> GetOneToOneMap( List<IElementMap> abc, List<IElementMap> xyz,double asd)
```

Now I have a an List object of type ElementInfo

```
List<ElementInfo> analyinfo;
```

when I call the method `GetOneToOneMap` I am currently sending the first argument as `analyinfo.Cast<IElementMap>` but I do not want to use `.Cast`

What are better ways to do this?

Comment: http://automapper.org/ - "A convention-based object-object mapper. 100% organic and gluten-free. Takes out all of the fuss of mapping one object to another."

Comment: _"I do not want to use `.Cast`"_ Why not - it appears to be the appropriate solution?  If you can explain why you don't want to use it, perhaps someone can suggest a better alternative that suits your needs.

Comment: A `List<ElementInfo>` _is not_ a `List<IElementMap>`, otherwise you could add other implementations to it`  You need to either cast each item to a new collection type or change the parameter types to `IEnumerable<IElementMap>` which is covariant.

Comment: May be you should ask yourself why your method accepts arguments of type `List<IElementMap>`. What specific methods/properties of the `List<T>` class are you using inside. Can they be provided by some **covariant** interface implemented by the `List<T>` class (because the class is **invariant**).

Comment: You might be able to use `IReadOnlyList<T>` which is also covariant but includes an indexer.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the type of `abc` and `xyz` parameters to `IEnumerable<IElementMap>` then you can pass a `List<ElementInfo>` as parameter.

This is possible since `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant in `T`.

Something like this:

```
public static IDictionary<int,int> GetOneToOneMap(IEnumerable<IElementMap> abc, 
                                                  IEnumerable<IElementMap> xyz, 
                                                  double asd)
{
    ...
}
```

Then a call like this is possible:

```
List<ElementInfo> list1 = ...;
List<ElementInfo> list2 = ...;

GetOneToOneMap(list1, list2, 123);
```

Another solution would be using generics, like so:

```
public static IDictionary<int, int> GetOneToOneMap<T>(IEnumerable<T> abc,
                                                      IEnumerable<T> xyz,
                                                      double asd) where T : IElementMap
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list could be of type IElementMap and items added to it can be of type ElementInfo.

```
List<IElementMap> analyinfo=new List<IElementMap> {objects of ElementInfo};
```

This way you dont have to cast analyinfo while passing to GetOneToOneMap method.

Comment: That's basically the same thing that `Cast().ToList()` does.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe,
Enumerable.OfType is your friend
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That basically does the same thing as `Cast` if all of the items are of the destination type.

Comment: Sure it basically the same but the advantage is OfType will filtered the objects for you that are matching the parameter. Otherwise you should use overide to performe serval parameter types.